# What is the load on this DC HV bias supply?

Tags: dc, high-voltage, load

Most proportional HV supplies' outputs are load dependent. Given the circuit below, what is the load on the bias supply? Which components contribute to the load the most? The "detector" is an ionization chamber with capacitance on the order of pF and is AC coupled to an opamp via the 0.01uF capacitor.

[image: circuit]

Comment: Depends on the leakage through the capacitors and the detector. And on the voltage of the bias supply, and whatever's to the right of that 10 nF capacitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Essentially the Ion Chamber is the main load.

It is a high voltage capacitor or dielectric insulator with very little contamination that controls the baseline leakage current. Thus the 100M and 10M must be much smaller than this which serves as current limiter and AC noise suppression respectively. The ionization of bipolar molecules is what is detected by the high-energy collision of particles/waves as current.  This means **BOTH AC coupled capacitors** must have better insulation "purity"   than the expected clean chamber so they do not contribute to HV DC load current.

The DC load is the sum of (10M(neglect) + 100M + detector + low leakage Req of capacitor(neglect)).

Generally, the detector is much higher R than 100M except during the picosecond (?) *after* ionization or gas molecule detonation and creating an ion pair flowing charge in a weak electromagnetic field.  The 100Mohm R is a safety current limiter of I=V/100M.

Thus the detection of gas detonation from high-energy particles streaming between the plates is the number of particles flowing per second, measured as a small transient to the steady DC load.    The AC load does not consume DC power, yet over time, as the tube ages from insulation contamination from dust, the leakage current may rise.

[image]  Credit : Doug Sim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Detector_regions.gif

The capacitor chosen for low-leakage is likely a PP polypropylene film cap in the region of \$>>10^{12} \Omega\$

Answer (score 2):

The load is whatever leaks through the detector and through the capacitor.

The manufacturer of the detector will specify the leakage (if it is significant,) as will the capacitor manufacturer.

Capacitor manufacturers may define the leakage as a resistance proportional to the capacitance (ΩF) or as a fixed resistance.  [This Murata page](https://www.murata.com/en-us/support/faqs/capacitor/ceramiccapacitor/char/0039) goes into some depth on the subject.  Divide bias voltage by the calculated (or fixed) resistance of your capacitor to get the leakage current.

[This guide for an ionization detector](https://www.standardimaging.com/uploads/tech_notes/4812-00_IonChamber-LeakageMeasurement_TechNote.pdf) says that the expected leakage current for that particulator model is ±0.050 pA.  Other models will have different values, though I expect any usable ionization detector will have a very low leakage current.